# Axis's Plot Show Wrong Output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, stock

I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
import yfinance as yf
df = yf.download('AAPL',
                 start='2001-01-01',
                 end='2005-12-31',
                 progress=False)
df.head()
df = df.reset_index()
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y%m%d')
df.dropna(how='any', inplace=True)
# Plot the returns
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('Dates')
plt.ylabel('Prices')
plt.plot(df['Close'])
plt.title('Close Price', fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

The output of the close price plot is
[image]

We can see that the dates and price didn't show correct output. I have checked the type of dataframe's date.

```
df.info()
```

The results is
[image]

I have tried some ways but it didn't work. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reset the index. The index `Dates` is already a `datetime`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
import yfinance as yf
df = yf.download('AAPL',
                 start='2001-01-01',
                 end='2005-12-31',
                 progress=False)
# df.head()
# df = df.reset_index()  # <- DON'T DO THAT
# df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y%m%d')  # <- DON'T DO THAT
# df.dropna(how='any', inplace=True)
# Plot the returns
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('Dates')
plt.ylabel('Prices')
plt.plot(df['Close'])
plt.title('Close Price', fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

[image]

To modify the date axis, read [Date tick labels](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html) from matplotlib documentation.